# How to change the outerHTML attributes in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have implemented javascriptspellchecker in my page.
After implementation in my textbox, `display : none visibility:hidden`  is directly added as an attribute for the outerHTML. I want to edit the same. basically I want to remove that display : none, because of which my textbox is not displaying properly.

Comment: maybe spell checker is adding that attribute to the textbox?

Comment: Ya, But I want to override that attribute, because I can't remove spellchecker

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to target all inputs with a specific class and then display them like so

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/z3cqrsg1/

html

```
Firstname : 
<input id="firstname" class="spellchecker" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></input>
<br />
Lastname : 
<input id="lastname" class="spellchecker" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></input>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    alert($('input.spellchecker').length);
    $('input.spellchecker').show();
    $('input.spellchecker').css('visibility', 'show');
});
```

Or you can use javascript like so

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/z3cqrsg1/1/

html

```
Firstname : 
<input id="firstname" class="spellchecker" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></input>
<br />
Lastname : 
<input id="lastname" class="spellchecker" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></input>
```

javascript

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("spellchecker").length);

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('spellchecker');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    elements[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Also just a side note, in my jQuery example make sure not to run `$('input.spellchecker')` multiple times. Just call it once and store that into a variable, this is applied to my javascript example.